# Not able to delete in @OneToMany relationship spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

In my spring boot project, I have one `LineItem` entity below is the code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "scenario_lineitem")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class LineItem implements Cloneable {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GoogleConfigConstant.class);

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)   
    private BigInteger lineItemId;

    @Column
    private String name; 

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinColumn(name = "line_item_meta_id")
    private List<QuickPopValue> quickPopValues;   
}
```

Another entity is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "quick_pop_value")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class QuickPopValue implements Cloneable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "quick_pop_value_id", columnDefinition = "bigint(20)", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private BigInteger quickPopValueId;

    @Column(name = "column_name")
    private String columnName;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;

    @Column(name = "formula", columnDefinition = "longtext")
    private String formula;
}
```

Now I am trying to delete `QuickPopValue` one by one but it's not getting deleted and not getting any exception as well.

Below is the delete code :

```
List<QuickPopValue> quickPopValues = sheetRepository.findByColumnName(columnName);
for (QuickPopValue qpValue : quickPopValues) {
    quickPopValueRepository.delete(qpValue);
}
```

Comment: did you check sheetRepository.findByColumnName is returning values ? and also share the code for sheetRepository and quickPopValueRepository

Comment: Like @dassum said show the repositories and also the packages. Could be that your `@Entity` is not seen by spring. Maybe in different packages and the componentScan don’t see them. Also did you include `@EnableJpaRepositories`? From what you show here it’s not clear why it’s not working. This part of code looks fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such behavior occurs when deleted object persisted in the current session.

```java
for (QuickPopValue qpValue : quickPopValues) {
    // Here you delete qpValue but this object persisted in `quickPopValues` array which is 
    quickPopValueRepository.delete(qpValue);
}
```

To solve this you can try delete by id

```
@Modifying
@Query("delete from QuickPopValue t where t.quickPopValueId = ?1")
void deleteQuickPopValue(Long entityId);
```

```
for (QuickPopValue qpValue : quickPopValues) {
    quickPopValueRepository.deleteQuickPopValue(qpValue.getQuickPopValueId());
}
```

Comment: I implemented in this way and it works , but i am surprised it should work without query as well as it is working many other places in application  .

Comment: @HarishBagora use `deleteByQuickPopValueId(qpValue.getQuickPopValueId())` may work

Comment: I tried that method "deleteByQuickPopValueId"  but it does not work, its only working with query.